# Keras feeding a one dimension image array, specifying the right input shape

Tags: numpy, keras

I'm working on the cat vs dog classification model the code of loading the data below. What I've done is read the images with OpenCV then get the edges using edge detection and resize the images to 200,200 so at the end I've got a black and white image with the white colors beings the detected outline.

```
import os
import sys
import cv2

import random

from tqdm import tqdm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_images = os.listdir('data/train')
test_images = os.listdir('data/test')

test_images_data = []

for image in tqdm(test_images):
    image_data = cv2.imread('data/test/' + image)

    #Convert to GrayScale
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #convert color from BGR to RGB
    image_data = cv2.cvtColor(image_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_data = cv2.resize(image_data, (200, 200))

    #turn to only borders
    edges = cv2.Canny(image_data, 150, 150)

    test_images_data.append(edges)



train_images_data = []
train_images_labels = []

random.shuffle(train_images)

for image in tqdm(train_images):
    image_data = cv2.imread('data/train/' + image)

    #Convert to GrayScale
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #convert color from BGR to RGB
    image_data = cv2.cvtColor(image_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_data = cv2.resize(image_data, (200, 200))

    #turn to only borders
    edges = cv2.Canny(image_data, 150, 150)

    train_images_data.append(edges)

    if image.startswith('cat'):
        train_images_labels.append(0)
    else:
        train_images_labels.append(1)



from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D 
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense


model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape=train_images_data[0].shape)) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 

model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2))) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 

model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2))) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 

model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(64)) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(1)) 
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
            optimizer='rmsprop', 
            metrics=['accuracy']) 

model.fit(train_images_data, train_images_labels, epochs=150, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=10)
```

problem is when I run it like this I get this error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_16: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3
```

I've tried other input_shape values like

```
(200, 200, 1)
(200, 200, -1)
(1, 200, 200)
(-1, 200, 200)
```

None are working.

Answer (score 0):

Input shape : (200, 200, 1,) to let the batch size be the last dimension, hence 4dim is expected.

Comment: Doesn't work, gives back this error ```ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 25000 arrays: [array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0,...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was two folds. First I needed to turn the data from a list to a numpy array then reshape it.

```
train_images_data = np.array(train_images_data)
train_images_data = train_images_data.reshape([-1, 200, 200,1])
```

With that this now works

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(200, 200, 1)))
```